# How To Correctly Use glMultMatrix - iPhone - OpenGL ES

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es, 3d

I wonder if anyone can help me learn how to correctly use glMultMatrix.

I have the following render code in my app, however it appears I cannot just feed a C struct with the matrix to glMultMatrix :

```
-(void)render
{

matrixStruct matrices[] = {1, 0, -0, -9.37988, 0, -0.651537, 0.758617, 1133.64, 0, 0.758617, 0.651537, 129730, 0, 0, 0, 1};


// clear the matrix
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

//scale
glScalef(0.00001, 0.00001, 0.00001);

    glMultMatrixf(matrices);

[mesh render];

//restore the matrix
glPopMatrix();
}
```

I understand from the documentation at http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glMultMatrix.xml that I need to provide :

```
void glMultMatrixd( const GLdouble *    m);
void glMultMatrixf( const GLfloat *     m);

m
Points to 16 consecutive values that are used as the elements of a 4 × 4 column-major        matrix.
```

I am not sure how I should format my matrix and pass it to glMultMatrix. Also do I need to enable glMatrixMode before I call render ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you understand how matrices work in OpenGL? Pushing to and popping from the various matrix stacks and what each stack should be used for? Do you understand what glRotatef, glTranslatef and glScalef do and how they do it? I ask because I don't understand where you're having difficulty. Also, what is your matrix "matrices" for?

Comment: The difficulty is just the syntax around using glMultMatrix - what should I be passing to it ? The matrix "matrices" was my first attempt, but I think this is wrong.

Comment: I'v edited the code to improve the question - I know that I wouldn't use both glMultMatrix and the other gl matrix calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out - I needed to pass an array of floats :

e.g

float matrices[] ={1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,-578.556,7068.92,48.6953,1};

All working now - thanks.